# MobileFirst Foundation SDK 8.0 Init failure: Can't read checksum.js

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm following this tutorial https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

and I'm getting "Init failure: Can't read checksum.js" error at the start of the app launch.

I realize that cordova-plugin-mfp -> bootstrap.js is point to a "checksum.js" file,

```
var WORKLIGHT_CHECKSUM_PATH = WORKLIGHT_DIR + '/checksum.js';
```

I have try to search to whole project, but there is no such file in the project.

Please advice.

Comment: Please list your installed plugins and their versions. Also mention detailed reproduction steps.

Comment: running "cordova prepare" solves the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running "cordova prepare" solves the issue